# Html ajax order form, invoice for the produckt oredered

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have a html table with the following columns:
produkt name, quantity, price , orderand total amount.

Now the client will set the quantity he want to order, and automatically the total column to display the price without refreshing the page.

Also in a sidebar column to display the total amount of the product ordered and the amount. Kind of total invoice. Is this possible? 
Thank you in advance

```
<pre>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>produkt name</th>
    <th>quantity</th> 
    <th>price</th>
     <th>Order</th>
    <th>total amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
    <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smartphone</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
     <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
     <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can bind an event to the input. So when the value changes, the function is fired.

Then by using `parent()`, `prev()` and `text()` we can get the price.

With those values, we can calculate the total and insert that value inside the next tablecell.

I've commented the code, hope it makes sense!

```js
$('[name=amount]').on('change', function() {
  var amount = $(this).val(), /* get the amount, so the inputs value */
      price = $(this).parent().prev().text(), /* get the price */
      total = amount * price; /* calculate the total */
  $(this).parent().next().html( total ); /* insert it in the next tablecell */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>produkt name</th>
    <th>quantity</th> 
    <th>price</th>
     <th>Order</th>
    <th>total amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone</td>
    <td>34</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
    <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Smartphone</td>
    <td>56</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
     <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>45</td>
    <td>80</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="amount"></td>
     <td>xxx</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you :), it was what i was looking for. Can you help me also for the invoice part? Kind of to display all the products, quantity, price and total amount ( only the products it was set the oder value)  in a sidebar part?

Comment: Well, I always like to help. I here already made you a script from scratch. This isn't how Stackoverflow works... we help each other, with problems, we don't script complete scripts. So try it yourself, if you get stuck, we love to help out!

Comment: Can i ask if the input value is this:


<input type="hidden" name="cmimi[]" value="<?php echo $cmimi; ?>"/>